# Update .HTML with jQuery on button click

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble updating the HTML within an element with jQuery.
I have a form thats hidden, and onclick becomes visible, Im not sure if this can be the problem but for some reason I cant get it working?

My jQuery is...

```
   $(".bill-upd-submit").click(function() {
          var elem = $(this);
          $.post("update_bill.php", elem.parent(".bill-upd").serialize(), function(data) {

                 $(this).closest('li').find('.cost').html('asdasd');
                 return false;

                alert('done');
          });
    });
```

I've made a fiddle to show it in action...
http://jsfiddle.net/jTzyQ/1/

What im trying to do is update the

Comment: firstly remove the alert after return

Comment: Your fiddle isnt doing to work requesting some Ajax within it. Plus, it seems like you need to return false from the click handler, not the ajax callback if that is your intent.

Comment: Sorry that was to see if the action was working

Comment: ...or move it before the return...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need

```
elem.closest('li').find('.cost').html('asdasd');
```

instead than

```
$(this).closest('li').find('.cost').html('asdasd');
```

You are inside the call-back of the post to the server, I don't think `this` is the right thing.

Comment: No luck @MiMo, data is entered so the AJAX works but the html sitn being updated